# Pylint "Parameters differ" or "Too many arguments"

Tags: python, pylint

I am trying to subclass [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) and override the `Session.request` method, but I have run into a problem. If I try to put `*args` and `**kwargs` into the function signature, Pylint warns that "Parameters differ from overridden 'request' method". But, if I replace the args and kwargs with the actual arguments from the Requests package, then Pylint says "Too many arguments".

***args & **kwargs**

```
def request(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

**Full Arguments**

```
def request(self,
            method,
            url,
            params=None,
            data=None,
            headers=None,
            cookies=None,
            files=None,
            auth=None,
            timeout=None,
            allow_redirects=True,
            proxies=None,
            hooks=None,
            stream=None,
            verify=None,
            cert=None,
            json=None):
```

Is there a "correct" way to resolve this, or do I have to just suppress the warning?

Comment: See this thread for some interesting details: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1482